# Invalid condition in KeyConditionExpression: Multiple attribute names used in one condition

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I want to make a query on the dynamodb using graphql

`TableName: "JobInfo",
    IndexName: "tableauGSI",
    KeyConditionExpression: "tableauGSI_Tableau = tableau AND #D BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#D": "date" },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":startDate": startDate,
      ":endDate": days
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL"`

But when I execute the query I receive the error: "*Invalid condition in KeyConditionExpression: Multiple attribute names used in one condition*"

Comment: What are the partition key and sort key attributes for the GSI?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming "tableauGSI_Tableau" is your partition key, you are comparing it to a field named "tableau", which I believe is not allowed. If "tableau" is simply a value, you need to escape it or move it to ExpressionAttributeValues as well.